# Grab duration of outputcacheprofile programmatically in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-config, outputcache

Is there a way in ASP.NET to grab the `duration` of the outputcacheprofile programmatically?

```
<outputCacheProfiles>
          <add name="Documents" duration="600" enabled="false" varyByParam="*" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private int GetSetting()
{
    // Get the Web application configuration.
    System.Configuration.Configuration webConfig =
        WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");

    // Get the section.
    string configPath = "system.web/caching/outputCacheSettings";
    System.Web.Configuration.OutputCacheSettingsSection outputCacheSettings =
        (System.Web.Configuration.OutputCacheSettingsSection)webConfig.GetSection(
            configPath);

    // Get the profile at zero index.
    System.Web.Configuration.OutputCacheProfile outputCacheProfile =
        outputCacheSettings.OutputCacheProfiles[0];

    return outputCacheProfile.Duration;
}
```